# bash interactive menu, exit on empty input

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have tried to piece together a script to list different jws directories and allow user to select different client directories before it continues on to edit jnlp files within the directory.  I have the edit part working, I have the menu working mostly; I can't figure out how to exit the loop once the selections have been made.

I'd like it to exit once ENTER is hit without a number selection, and continue with the next part of the script.

```
function update_jnlp
{
 while :
  do
 # JNLP update submenu

options=($(ls /tmp/test/ | grep "jws$"))

menu() {
    clear
    echo "Locally installed jnlps:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do
       printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
    [[ "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg"; :
     }

prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
    while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
       [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
       (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
       { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
       ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
       [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
    done
printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do
       [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
    done
    done
    for i in ${choices[@]}; do
            printf "%s\n" ${choices[@]};
    echo "fun"
        done
        echo "@msg"
# here is the script to edit the files now contained as ${choices[@]}
 }
```

I recognize that I am in a menu loop and that I need to validate that input from the read command = "" or that $prompt input is null, and I assume I break from there

Comment: "*I recognize that I am in a menu loop and that I need to validate that input from the read command = "" or that $prompt input is null, and I assume I break from there*" Have you tried that?

Comment: I have, but I think I just can't get the order of operation right, or syntax.

Comment: *$prompt input is null* What value should `$prompt` have to be "null"? Try to print it and see what it contains, if you mean when it's not set, try `[ "$prompt" ] || break`. The `read` is stored in `$num`. To see if it's the empty string, use exactly the same `[ "$num" ] || break`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please format your code more readably. As it stands, the erratic indentation makes it close to unreadable. Well, the indentation combined with defining a function in the body of a loop inside another function, and some of the more inscrutable loop bodies I've ever seen. (I thought I'd seen quite a lot; clearly, I've still got some learning to do.)

With the code formatted somewhat more orthodoxly, you have:

```
function update_jnlp
{
    while :
    do
        # JNLP update submenu
        options=($(ls /tmp/test/ | grep "jws$"))

        menu() {
            clear
            echo "Locally installed jnlps:"
            for i in ${!options[@]}; do
               printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
            done
            [[ "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg"; :
        }

        prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
        while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
            [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
            (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
            { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
            ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
            [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
        done

        printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
        for i in ${!options[@]}; do
            [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
        done

        echo "$msg"    # Added
        break          # Added

    done

    for i in ${choices[@]}; do
        printf "%s\n" ${choices[@]};
        echo "fun"
    done
    echo "@msg"
    # here is the script to edit the files now contained as ${choices[@]}
}
```

When I ran it, I selected 1, 3, 7 and then hit return, and the final page of output looked like:

```
Locally installed jnlps:
  1+) abc.jws
  2 ) def.jws
  3+) ghi.jws
  4 ) jkl.jws
  5 ) mno.jws
  6 ) pqr.jws
  7+) stu.jws
  8 ) vwx.jws
  9 ) xyz.jws
stu.jws was checked
Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): 
You selected abc.jws ghi.jws stu.jws
+
+
+
fun
+
+
+
fun
+
+
+
fun
@msg
```

Without the added `break`, you don't get to see what's selected because the outer `while :` loop clears the screen too quickly.  With the `echo "$msg"` added, you get `You selected nothing` as you'd want.

The material after the main `while :` loop is clearly not finalized.

In fact, you don't need the `while :` loop at all, or the incomplete material.  You could use:

```
function update_jnlp
{
    # JNLP update submenu
    options=($(ls /tmp/test/ | grep "jws$"))

    menu() {
        clear
        echo "Locally installed jnlps:"
        for i in ${!options[@]}; do
           printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
        done
        [[ "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg"; :
    }

    prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
    while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ -n "$num" ]]; do
        [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
        (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
        { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
        ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
        [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
    done

    printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do
        [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
    done
    echo "$msg"

}
```

That's still rather inscrutable, but at least it works more or less sanely.